# Incredibly slow performance when going to previous frame of a SWF movie

Tags: performance, flash, movieclip

In a SWF file, when I am using the following code to move backwards to a previous frame, it is incredibly slow -- Taking around 2 seconds. Where as moving forward to next frame takes 30-40 milli seconds.

```
movieClip.gotoAndStop(movieClip.totalFrames);//go the last frame of movie

while(movieClip.currentFrame>1) {
   var initTime:int = getTimer();
    movieClip.prevFrame();
    trace("Frame: "+movieClip.currentFrame+" Time taken:"+(getTimer()-initTime)/1000)        
 }
```

Here is the output i am getting (timings in seconds)

```
Frame: 84 Time taken:2.586
Frame: 83 Time taken:2.766
Frame: 82 Time taken:2.257
Frame: 81 Time taken:2.447
```

The SWF movie is generated from a PDF using SWFTools.

Size of the file : 5.8 MB
Number of Frames : 85

Any ideas on what to do differently to improve the performance of going to previous frame ?

Comment: Sure you are comparing moving to the same frame?  If you are moving forward from, say, frame 1 to frame 2, and there is nothing but a black square on the screen, you will always get better performance than, say, moving from frame 84 to 83, where the screen is filled with complex objects and transparencies...

Answer (score 1):

I reported this issue today on Adobe Jira:

http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASL-313

Answer (score 0):

Anyway: Using a while() loop to jump trough frames is not a good idea - the player will try to execute the instructions during one frame's time, while each MovieClip frame should be displayed for a long enough time to be registered by the human eye.  Have you tried this instead:

```
movieClip.gotoAndStop(movieClip.totalFrames);//go the last frame of movie

var timer : Timer = new Timer (100,999);
timer.addEventListener (TimerEvent.TIMER, , function () : void {
    var initTime:int = getTimer();
    movieClip.prevFrame();
    trace("Frame: "+movieClip.currentFrame+" Time taken:"+(getTimer()-initTime)/1000)        
});
timer.start();
```

Using Timer instead of a loop assures that switching between the actual frames takes long enough for each frame to be displayed properly - and for the function to stay within reasonable performance boundaries.